# Laravel 5 - Many to Many - Attach versus Save

Tags: php, laravel, save

I have a many to many relationship between two models, users and roles. Is there a difference between saving a relationship using the save() method and using the attach() method?

```
$user->roles()->save($role, ['expires' => $expires]); //using save
$user->roles()->attach($roleId, ['expires' => $expires]);// using attach
```

Are the two equivalent? I personally dont see the difference. Thoughts?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here is the snippet of code for the `save()` method. You'll see that it eventually calls `attach()`.

```
/**
 * Save a new model and attach it to the parent model.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model  $model
 * @param  array  $joining
 * @param  bool   $touch
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model
 */
public function save(Model $model, array $joining = [], $touch = true)
{
    $model->save(['touch' => false]);
    $this->attach($model->getKey(), $joining, $touch);
    return $model;
}
```

One big difference is that it also saves the model that you are passing to it. In other words, you can essentially create a new role (or even update the old one) while also attaching it to the user. For example:

```
// Get the user
$user = User::first();

// Instantiate a new role
$role = new Role($attributes);

// Creates the role / persists it into the database and attaches this role to the user
$user->roles()->save($role, ['expires' => $expires]);
```

Comment: If I save() a new role to a user that does not exist in the roles table, it will create a new role record in the roles database? So basically using a save() will never give us an error but using an attach() may give us a foreign key error if the role does not exist?

Comment: @alaboudi In a sense, yes, but I believe `attach()` won't throw an error either if you pass a new instance of a model. It just won't attach anything because the model doesn't exist in the database. However, `save()` will go the extra step of saving it to the database first if it doesn't exist or updating it if it needs to be updated before attaching it.